# Hydraulic disc brake - lever slowly touches bar

Tags: maintenance, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have a magura disc brake. When I pull the lever and keep applying constant pressure to it, it slowly retracts all the way to touch the bar. This process takes about 10 / 15 seconds. I have tried to bleed several times, even did a gravity bleed, and nothing seems to change. I installed the lever brand new, and the caliper did not have this problem with the previous lever. There is no signs of oil leak. Anyone has seen this before?

Comment: So weird, deffo sounds like a typical air in system or oil leak (not saying it must me). When you bleed the brake, did you make sure the caliper was bleed too? ie not just the through the lever? Have you ridden the bike since bleeding? ie bubbles in the hose might be tricky to move to the lever so they stay there, riding vibration might get them up to the lever

Comment: Due absence of oil leaks, suspect the no return valve in the lever is not sealing and leaking fluid back into the reservoir. If you squeeze hard and quickly, it teh lever squishy or firm? (Squishy means air).

Comment: I also agree with @mattnz. most likely scenario is that the piston and reservoir valve somehow failed and allowed the oil back into the reservoir.

Comment: While testing it on the stand yesterday, the lever has completely failed. When squeezed oil comes out from the circular cap at the outward facing side of the reservoir (on shimano xt lever) ... I am hoping this is covered by warranty.. Reading online suggested that's an overflow valve, but it doesnt hold any pressure at all now..

Comment: Before this happened the lever felt perfect as long as you didn't maintain the pressure. Not squishy, nice and firm.. Maintaining the pressure (not gorilla strength, same as you'd use to gradually stop) and the lever slowly moved back with consistent pace to the bars..